# push notification for web setBackgroundMessageHandler

Tags: javascript, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

This might be a very dumb question.
But how is this code handling the notifications when the window is not in focus in background?

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

When the app has the browser focus , the received message is handled through the onMessage callback in index.html.

When the app does not have browser focus then the setBackgroundMessageHandler callback in firebase-messaging-sw.js is where the received message is handled.

But strangely the setBackgroundMessageHandler written in firebase-messaging-sw.js is supposed to give a totally different push notification/message irrespective of the content(payload) of the original notification.

I am sending the notification via postman.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: The behavior that you describe is indeed how notifications work in a browser. What's your question?

Comment: I have clear understanding of the behaviour but this code implements the setBackgroundMessageHandler in firebase-messaging-sw.js. It never gets executed. This is my question. Why that implemented method deosn't get fired at all? I might be missing something silly, but I still cannot figure it out. You will have to go throught the firebase-messaging-sw.js code in the git repo shared above.

Comment: I've implemented notifications in a browser based on that quickstart. So you'll have to share a bit more on what you did. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful to figure out why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/71 
This solved the problem for now.
Missed going through this.